# pyinstaller no module named error

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, fedora

first of all: python 2.7, pyinstaller 3.3.1

I am new to pyinstaller and flask, and I am trying to develop a little app for my embedded linux system.

The key point is that each time I generate my app with pyinstaller, it works, but when I run it, it does not.

My last error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "flask/app.py", line 943, in run
  File "werkzeug/serving.py", line 812, in run_simple
  File "werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 273, in run_with_reloader
  File "werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 152, in run
  File "werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 22, in _iter_module_files
  File "email/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
ImportError: No module named image
```

As far as I am concerned, I do not need this module, but to me, the most important thing is knowing where to find those hidden dependencies. What I really want to know is a method in order to look for those dependencies and change my script for generating my bunddle with pyinstaller. Till now, I use this line for generating my bunddle:

pyinstaller --noupx --hiddenimport email.mime.message --hiddenimport image hello.py

The second hidden import is wrong, but, how can I know which import is missing??? Where do I have to search those modules?

My first hidden import (email.mime.message) had a similar message that just said that there was a missing import "message". I could read [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2481) the solution for that, but it was a matter of luck!

How do I know from that message what is the necessary dependency??

Thranks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You should run this for it to work:

```
pyinstaller -F -w \
--onefile \
--hidden-import='email.mime.multipart' \
--hidden-import='email.mime.message' \
--hidden-import='email.mime.text' \
--hidden-import='email.mime.image' \
--hidden-import='email.mime.audio' \
--hidden-import='sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator' \
--hidden-import='jinja2' \
main.py
```

Thanks to [mrf345](https://gist.github.com/mrf345/df900b93245ae60b2dae8e36d4d1f191)

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files, eval_statement, collect_submodules

datas = collect_submodules('email.mime')

hidden_imports = ['sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator', 'jinja2'] + datas
```

add this to your .spec file generated from the pyi-makespec, More info at 
https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html#understanding-pyinstaller-hooks